# choose data source type in rdlc

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I am using microsoft reporting (rdlc).I want to add dataset to my rdlc.

On adding new dataset the data source type is always database.I want to change it to Object.

The window for selecting data source type is not found

How can I choose data source type?

Comment: It should ask you, when you add a new datasource (not dataset)

Comment: I tried it but its not coming..It comes with windows application but not with web..

Comment: Can you create a datasource in your project itself?

Comment: yes...I tried from a class

Comment: @remyaviswan make sure you have a method that returns a Datatable